# Youtube audio Continues to play after closing Prettyphoto

Tags: jquery, youtube, prettyphoto

I have this problem in IE8 & 9 where the audio of a youtube video continues to run after clicking on the close button of the PrettyPhoto pop up. It does not occur in other browsers.

I'm using Prettyphoto version 3.1.3 (downgraded from 3.1.5, due to some other prettyphoto bugs)

You can test it yourselve at www.zomerkriebels.nl en click on the blue atermovie button

Answer (score 0):

$.prettyPhoto.close = function(){

```
        $('#nonPrettyPhotoIframeId').attr('src','');

    if($pp_overlay.is(":animated")) return;

    $.prettyPhoto.stopSlideshow();

        $('#pp_full_res iframe').attr('src', $('#pp_full_res iframe').attr('src'));

    $pp_pic_holder.stop().find('object,embed').css('visibility','hidden');
```

Edit it and it work like charm...

Answer (score -1):

only upgrade the plugin to ver 3.1.5 and add rel=prettyphoto for me its work

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?